# Trying to build a Gateway using Tomcat, but request from chrome gets redirected to end point

Tags: java, google-chrome, tomcat

I'm trying to build a simple gateway in Tomcat, which would do authorization checks and redirect the request to different endpoint, which gets the response and sends it back to the browser.

In Tomcat I have have a simple Servlet, which uses HttpURLConnection to connect to the endpoint, which gets the response and send it back to browser.

However in Chrome my URL always gets redirected to the endpoint domain. I don't see this behavior in IE or Firefox.

For example, this is deployed to hostname test.gateway.com.
If I make a http request test.gateway.com:9500/test/index.html from browser, Servlet should make a http request to test.endpoint.com/test/index.html and return the response. Client browser should remain on test.gateway.com:9500/test/index.html

However on Chrome my URL changes to http://test.endpoint.com/test/index.html

In my web.xml I have URL Mapping which calls this servlet.

Here is the Code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class AppProxyServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/AppProxyServlet")
public class AppProxyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final String proxy = "http://test.endpoint.com";


    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public AppProxyServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    private String callEndpoint(HttpServletRequest request, String plexURL)
            throws Exception {
        // make
        String queryString = request.getQueryString();
        if (queryString != null && queryString.length() > 0) {
            plexURL += "?" + queryString;
        }
        URL obj = new URL(plexURL);
        Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();

        StringBuffer allCookies = new StringBuffer();

        if (cookies != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                // if( cookies[ i ].getName() == "SSO")
                {
                    allCookies.append(cookies[i].getName());
                    allCookies.append("=");
                    if ("SSO".equals(cookies[i].getName())) {
                        String ssostr = cookies[i].getValue();

                        allCookies.append(ssostr);
                    } else {
                        allCookies.append(cookies[i].getValue());
                    }

                    if (i < cookies.length)
                        allCookies.append(";");
                    // con.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookies[ i
                    // ].getName()+"="+cookies[i].getValue());
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("All Cookies:" + allCookies.toString());
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1");
        con.setRequestProperty("Cookie", allCookies.toString());

        con.setRequestMethod("GET");

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

        System.out.println("\nSending Get request to URL:" + plexURL);
        System.out.println("Response code:" + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                con.getInputStream(), "ISO-8859-1")); // iso-8859-1

        int value;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((value = in.read()) != -1) {
            char c = (char) value;
            response.append(c);
        }

        con.disconnect();

        return (response.toString());           

    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // ServletContext sc = getServletContext();
        StringBuilder URL = new StringBuilder("");
        String URI = request.getRequestURI();
        System.out.println("Full URL:" + URI);

            // Form the URL
            URL.append(proxy);
            URL.append(URI);

            String sspResponse = "";
            if (URI.endsWith("css")) {
                response.setContentType("text/css");
            } else {
                response.setContentType("text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1");
            }

            PrintWriter printWriter = response.getWriter();

            try {
                sspResponse = callEndPoint(request, URL.toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
                System.out.println("Some exception occured...");
            }

            printWriter.println(sspResponse);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

Comment: can you supply some code?

Comment: I think you mean "proxies" and not "redirects", yes?

Comment: This is not a true proxy